# Finding max value in list of Object using Liquid syntax

Tags: liquid

I have a JSON response:

```
{"to_send":true,
 "cart_items":[{"product_name":"Boys Waist Coat Shirt-Trouser and Cap- Grey",
                "color":"Gray",
                "size":"80 (6M-1 Years)",
                "quantity":1,
                "sub_total":1189.0},
               {"product_name":"Boys Shirt, Pants And Coat - 3 Pcs Set With Bow - Dark Blue",
                "color":"Navy",
                "size":"2T (6M-1 Years)", 
                "quantity":2, 
                "sub_total":3418.0}]}
```

How can I find max price item/product in above O/P in liquid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how in liquid syntax, another way would be to create a custom filter/tag

```
{% assign max_price = 0 %}
{% for item in obj.cart_items %}
    {% if item.sub_total > max_price %}
       {% assign max_price = item.sub_total %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<p>Max price: {{max_price}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get min or max value is possible also with `first` and `last` filter. But array must be sorted first:

```
{% assign max = obj.cart_items | sort: "sub_total" | last %}
```